# Adding a value to a cell breaks conditional formatting in google sheets using gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a google sheets worksheet which looks like this:

```
col1        col2        col3        col4
ABC         10          ABC         145.1
ABC         15.5        ABC         574.5
ABC         26.7        ABC         45.4
```

I mark cells red if their value is less than a given value and it works:

```
rule = ConditionalFormatRule(
    ranges=[GridRange.from_a1_range('B:D', worksheet)],
    booleanRule=BooleanRule(
        condition=BooleanCondition('NUMBER_LESS', ['100']),
        format=CellFormat(backgroundColor=Color(0.992, 0.529, 0.529))
    )
)

rules = get_conditional_format_rules(worksheet)
rules.append(rule)
rules.save()
```

I add `%` sign to `col2 & col4` like so:

```
cell_list = [worksheet.range('B2:B4'), worksheet.range('D2:D4')]

sign_to_add = '%'

for item in cell_list:
    for val in item:
        val.value = val.value + sign_to_add 
        
for item in cell_list:
    worksheet.update_cells(item)
```

```
col1        col2        col3        col4
ABC         10%         ABC         145.1%
ABC         15.5%       ABC         574.5%
ABC         26.7%       ABC         45.4%
```

But this breaks the conditional formatting I've done above. If I switch code places the formatting does not work as the cell looks like this once clicked on it in google sheets:

> '10%

note the ' in the front

Is there a way to achieve the conditional formatting while being able to add `%` sign to a cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about adding `value_input_option='USER_ENTERED'` to the method of `update_cells` as follows? It seems that the default value of [`value_input_option`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption) is `RAW`. By this, `'` is added.

#### From:

```
worksheet.update_cells(item)
```

#### To:

```
worksheet.update_cells(item, value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
```

#### Note:

- In this case, when your script is run, `145.1` becomes `145.1%`. By this, this value is less than `100`. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [update_cells(cell_list, value_input_option='RAW')](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v4.0.1/api.html?highlight=update_cells#gspread.models.Worksheet.update_cells)

Comment: Thank you for your input, will try that out. But why would  `145.1%` be less than 100? Does it try to compare it to somekind of ASCII string values?

Comment: @Jonas Palačionis Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I think that `145.1%` is `1.451`. When `145.1%` is put to a cell as `value_input_option='USER_ENTERED'`, this value is converted to the value of percentage. In this case, this value is used as the number. When `'145.1%` is used, this value is used as the string.

Comment: I tried that out and the conditional formatting works as expected, In reality, I check for negative values, all negative values have a red background while all positives have a neutral background, the `%` sign does not affect this conditional formatting. Thank you for your answer.